# How to create a frame to-fit different images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, template-design

my request is nothing very advanced (the way I think it should be done at least).

I blog for a business, and part of "keeping the style throughout" is applying a specific frame.
That frame comes from iLife's Keynote (it's a standard picture frame we apply to most pictures).

[image: the frame from Keynote which I think he's using]

The crappy thing about that frame is that on the sides and edges, it's not transparent. If it were, my issues would be long resolved.

What I want to do:
I want to be able to apply that frame (on photoshop or wherever) to any picture, without having to worry about the aspect ratio. 
I suppose I have to create my own template out of that frame. I don't want to distort the pixels, so I also guess I would have to make a somewhat high-res template, too.

Is there any way to at least partly automate the process? create a template that I can use in the future?
Ideally I would like to apply the frame without having to do any touch-ups.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the frame so we can get an idea of it's complexity? Not everyone uses Keynote.

Comment: Is the final output a JPG image with the frame included?

Comment: Will this always be used online? You could create an image for the corners and then an image for the top/bottom and an image for the sides and then add them as elements to a css layout to be applied to all images...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best solution would be to implement the `border-image` property within the actual `css` code for the web site. The property is [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/border-image) with the use of the vendor prefixes (except IE of course).

A nice tutorial on the topic is available at [THIS SITE](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/)

The basic principal would be to set the corners to be a section of the border-image, and allow the top and sides to repeat the smaller, non-critical section.